# Doxygen multiple arguments list without break the line

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen

I have another Doxygen question.

Is there a way to keep multiple arguments of a function/method... "aligned", without line breaks, just like if we have one single argument?

[image: Multiple Arguments with Line Break]

I don't like this way because I'm trying my best to not to be forced to follow [PSR-2 #4.4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#44-method-arguments) and this is ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few tries I realized how to do.

It's only a matter of adding a **float: left** in/for selector **.memname tr**

This can be done manually in *Doxygen.css* file or in a additional Stylesheet defined to be added after the main one through *HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET* option in *HTML* section.

> By doing it in *Doxygen.css* file you may have to repeat every time you generate the documentation.

However, when documenting code written in weakly typed languages, like PHP, most of the times you will not have an argument type and yet an "empty" (because it's not really empty) **<td>** designed to store such information will still be added right before the one where the argument name will be placed. E.g.:

```
<tr>
    <td class="paramkey"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="paramtype">&#160;</td>
    <td class="paramname"><em>$extra</em>&#160;</td>
</tr>
```